# Windows 8.1 Factory Reset w/ BitLocker Encryption

Tags: windows-8.1, system-restore, bitlocker

**Why I am doing this:**

I recently downloaded the wrong graphics card driver update and my graphics card has gone haywire. After trying a bunch of things NVIDIA had me do, including to install the right driver, NVIDIA wants me to perform a system restore but I unfortunately had my restore point timmer turned off, so there are no saved restore points.

**Background:**

I will need to perform a factory reset but a lot has changed on my computer since I bought it. I immediately upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro and installed BitLocker encryption.

**Question:**

What are the pitfalls I may encounter when reverting back to factory settings while installing encryption after getting the computer from the factory and how can I perform a safe restore?

Comment: Just reinstall windows 8.1 pro there are no pitfalls your encrypted data will be lost unless you back it up but your plan seems over kill for a simple driver probldm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 Factory Reset w/ Upgraded SSD and OS on that new SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/829562/windows-8-1-factory-reset-w-upgraded-ssd-and-os-on-that-new-ssd)

Comment: @Kevin Panko Can you read? That post is for an upgraded drive and this post is for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Primary pitfall is that you might/will lose all of your data depending on how you go about it, so perform a backup. Store the backup on a different device. A classic "factory reset" is supposed to remove all your data from the device.

Secondary pitfall is that you may not be able to do a factory reset because the factory reset partition no longer exists and you might not have a CD.

Third pitfall is that you may run into a classic issue where some drivers that you need are not included and you need to install them. This is a most interesting problem if the driver in question is for the network card, since this makes downloading the correct drivers slightly more difficult. Make sure you have another device with internet access available just in case, and a way to transfer data between the 2. This won't be an issue if you do a "factory reset" from a recovery partition, only if you do a reinstall from a Microsoft Windows CD.

Last but not least, you may have software installed that uses product keys, or that requires to be uninstalled from one machine before you can install it on another one. If you want to avoid support calls, make sure you still have these product keys, resp. uninstall the software, as necessary. Some tools exist that can extract the keys of already installed software, but only as long as the software is still on the machine. A similar issue are stored passwords for services like Steam. If you forgot the password, you will need to go through Steam to reset it.

Comment: Correct me please if I'm wrong to ask this question here, but since I have the extended warranty on my laptop would you recommend I send it in and have a professional take care of this because based on your answer it sounds like a lot can truly go wrong.

Comment: I doubt this is covered by extended warranty. Software rarely is. A factory reset will not go wrong. installing your stuff afterwards might go wrong if you didn't back it up properly first. The professional will not help with that.