# Windows 8.1 Factory Reset w/ Upgraded SSD and OS on that new SSD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, operating-systems, system-restore

**Why I am doing this:**

I download the wrong graphics card driver update and now my graphics card has gone haywire. After trying several things with NVIDIA, including installing the right driver,  and having no luck NVIDIA wants me to perform a system restore but unfortunately I had my restore point timmer turned off and no restore points have ever been saved.

**Background:**

I will need to do a factory reset. My laptop came with two available drive slots (We'll call them Slot A and Slot B) and one of them (Slot A) was filled by a HDD which held the OS. Slot A on the laptop has to be the drive that holds the OS. I bought another drive a SSD and wanted to put the OS on it, so I did not place the new SSD in slot B. Instead I took the HDD out of slot A and but the HDD in slot B. Then I put the SSD in slot A and installed the OS on the SSD using the tools that Samsung gave me (software cd).

**Question:**

Now, I am wondering if this will affect my factory reset because won't the factory settings be expecting the HDD to be in slot A? What are the things that could potentially occur while performing a full system restore with changed hardware since the time of the factory settings?

Comment: um what? Why can't you just rollback the driver and reinstall the correct one? Do you mean a system restore as in reinstalling windows or what since you said you never had a restore point?

Comment: NVIDIA and I tried reinstalling the correct driver but my computer still crashes with a graphics card error when I do things like Google Earth or play games. They said they can no longer help me until I perform a system restore. When I went to do that I realized my computer has no restore points saved. So I think I need to go all the way back to factory settings, i.e., set my computer back to as if it were brand new. If I'm wrong about something please let me know because I'm a young novice.

Comment: Well I assume you mean a "factory reset" as reinstalling windows but running it from a restore partition? Then just run it. There won't be an issue with them being in different slots.

Comment: People come here because they're not an expert like you may be. I had the name wrong, so I will edit the post but downvoting a valid question for that is disappointing at best. If that is the answer you should make it official and I will upvote it and mark it as correct. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I didn't mean for my answer to come across as rude at all. I was just trying to clarify is all :)

Comment: You weren't rude but I've usual always had successful posts on Stackoverflow and I feel like everytime I come to SuperUser with a question everyone eats me alive and downvotes me. Not everyone is able to get the exact lingo and names of things correct, if we were able to do that we would most likely know the answer to our questions. It would be so nice if this community would realize that we are all a group of kind people wanting to help when we can! :) thanks.

Comment: Possible reasons: For downvote -- Lack of research effort: "I am wondering if this will affect my factory reset because won't the factory settings be expecting the HDD to be in slot A?", What happened when you tried? where are you getting stuck exactly?  Votes to close -- Too-broad: "What are the things that could potentially occur while performing a full system restore with changed hardware since the time of the factory settings?". Lots of stuff, including nuclear war; but really, it completely depends on the backup and restore process used by your notebook manufacturer.

Comment: You can't "damage" a computer by attempting to install software.   That attempt would be the "research" I was driving at, and it's well within your ability to try (if not, you should give up and take it to a pro). If you're worried about losing data, make a backup first, which should be a given when planning on (re)installing an OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no system restore points and it is recommended by Nvidia to do a "system restore" then run the windows restore located on your restoration partition.  Moving the drives from one slot to another won't make any difference since during the reinstall, it will ask you to select the appropriate drive anyways.  When it does ask, make sure you pick the drive that currently has windows on it.  Also make sure that your new install is a full install and not an "upgrade" when it asks to ensure everything is wiped.